# iPhone - MPMusicPlayerController - Selecting audio from the queue and play it

Tags: iphone, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm using MPMusicPlayerController in my application. I'm setting a queue using method "setQueueWithItemCollection". I'm able to play the songs, move to prev/next songs etc.
But how can I make MPMusicPlayerController play some 5th song from the queue?

Comment: what you want to do? directy play 5th song?

Comment: Yes, I want to play 5th song directly

Comment: Can be any event like click of a button or selection from a table view etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to maintain another list of queue in your application.
Then everytime, when you to jump to another song, get players current item, compare it from your array iterating through it and at the same time use skip to prev or next song from music player.
no other solution found.

Comment: How fast is this solution for say an array of 1,000 songs? (If we wanted to skip to track 500)

Answer (score 2):

when you set the queue, save the queue somewhere else that you can access.
if you want to play the fifth song, use MPMusicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem= [[queue items] objectAtIndex:4] and it will play the fifth song. you don't have to skip 5 times.